# Determine if relation $R$ is an equivalence relation and if it is describe the equivalence classes. $(x-y) \cup (y-x)$

Tags: solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

The question is stated as: Determine if the relation $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ and If it is, describe the equivalence classes.

- $A$ is the set of all subsets of the set of integers
- $R = \{(x,y) : x \in A \land y \in A \land (x-y) \cup (y-x)$ is a finite set$\}$
- Hint: $xRy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ differ by only a finite number of elements

My problem is when trying to show the transitive property of $R$ and to understand the equivalence classes. Let me know if a did it correct and if the equivalence classes well described.

Showing that $R$ is an equivalence relation:

1. $R$ is reflexive

For any set we have by definition that the difference to itself is $\emptyset$, thus $(\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow (x-x) \cup (x-x) = \emptyset)$, as empty set is a finite set we have that $(\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow xRx)$ and therefore $R$ is reflexive.

2. $R$ is symmetric

By assumption if $xRy$, we have that $(x-y) \cup (y-x)$ is a finite set, but as union is just a specific case of arbitrary union we have that:
$$\bigcup_{A \in\{(x-y), (y-x)\}}A = (x-y) \cup (y-x) = (y-x) \cup (x-y)$$
thus if $(x-y) \cup (y-x)$ is a finite set then $(y-x) \cup (x-y)$ is too because they are the same set, from this we have.

$(\forall x)(\forall y)(xRy \Rightarrow yRx)$ and then R is symmetric.

3. $R$ is transitive

- First assume that $xRy \land yRz$ then we should show that $xRz$ holds true

The first observation i did in this part is that $xRy$ is true for any pair of finite sets from A, and the second is that if two sets from $A$ are disjoint then these need to be finite to be in $R$. Both observation come from the Hint on question. from now on we have $(xRy \land yRz \Rightarrow xRz)$ holds true for any finite $x,y,z$ in $A$

Now lets assume $x$ is a set from $A$ with infinite number of elements and as $xRy$ is true by assumption we have that $x-y$ is a finite set, as $x$ and $y$ differ by a finite number of elements they need to have infinite elements in common, then $y$ need to be a set with infinite number of elements to $xRy$ hold true.

But if $y$ have infinite number of elements and we have $yRz$ by assumption, we have that $z$ need to have infinite number of elements too, thus in our assumption of $xRy \land yRz$ we have that if $x$ is a set with infinite number of elements then $y$ and $z$ are too.

From $xRy \land yRz$ we have that $(x-y), (y-x), (y-z), (z-y)$ are all finite sets.

Let $x_f = x-y$ then $x \subseteq x_f \cup y$

Lets define the set $(x_f \cup y) - z$:

$$ p \in (x_f \cup y) - z \Leftrightarrow (p \in x_f \lor p \in y) \land p \notin z$$
$$ p \in (x_f \cup y) - z \Leftrightarrow (p \in x_f \land p \notin z) \lor (p \in y \land p \notin z)$$
$$ p \in (x_f \cup y) - z \Leftrightarrow (p \in (z_f - z) \lor p \in (y-z))$$
$$ p \in (x_f \cup y) - z \Leftrightarrow (p \in (z_f - z) \cup (y-z))$$
$$(x_f \cup y) - z \Leftrightarrow (z_f - z) \cup (y-z)$$
As $z_f$ is a finite set $(z_f - z)$ still finite, and $(y-z)$ is finite by our assumption, thus, we have that $(x_f \cup y) - z$ is a finite set because is equal to a union of two finite sets, and as we have $x \subseteq (x_f \cup y)$ we have also:
$$x - z \subseteq (x_f \cup y) - z$$ then as $x-z$ is a finite set because it a subset of a finite set.

If we let $z_f = z-y$ then its possible to follow the same process to conclude that $z-x$ is a finite set too, and if $(x-z)$ and $(z-x)$ are finite sets we have that $(x-z) \cup (z-x)$ is a finite set and therefore we have:

$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(xRy \land yRz \Rightarrow xRz)$.

so R is transitive, and it is a equivalence relation.

The equivalence classes consists on:

$[x] = \{z : z \in A \land x-z \cup z-x $ is a finite set$\}$

If the given set $x$ is a finite set then the equivalence class consist in the set of all finite sets in $A$, but if the given $x$ is a set with infinite number of elements the equivalence class consist of all the infinite sets in $A$ that differ by a finite number of elements from the given set.

Comment: I've struggled to follow your proof. To simplify the transitivity case I would suggest using / proving $(x-z) = ((x-y)-z) \cup ((y - z) \cap x)$. In particular if $(x-y)$ and $(y-z)$ are finite then so is $(x-z)$.

Comment: [1/2]
I can see that $(x-z)=((x−y)−z) \cup ((y−z) \cap x)$, but in a intuitive way, so I moved back to logic statements as following:

$$p \in ((x-y) - z) \cup ((y-z) \cap x) \Leftrightarrow ((p \in x \land p \notin y) \land p \notin z) \lor ((p \in y \land p \notin z) \land p \in x)$$
$$...\Leftrightarrow (p \in x \land (p \notin y \land p \notin z)) \lor (p \in x \land (p \in y \land p \notin z))$$
$$...\Leftrightarrow p \in x \land [(p \notin y \land p \notin z) \lor (p \in y \land p \notin z)]$$
$$...\Leftrightarrow p \in x \land [p \notin z \land (p \notin y \lor p \in y)]$$

Comment: [2/2]
$$... \Leftrightarrow p \in x \land [p \notin z \land \top]$$
$$... \Leftrightarrow p \in x \land p \notin z$$
$$... \Leftrightarrow p \in (x-z)$$
Thus,
$$((x-y)-z) \cup ((y-z) \cap x) = (x-z)$$

As both $(x-y)$ and $(y-z)$ are finite sets, we have that (x-z) are finite too as you stated, I dont managed to reach the equality you posted here before, thats why I did it in a more complex manner using unions. But i got your idea its really good.

What about the description of the equivalence classes?

Consider posting your idea as an answer, then I will accept.